# If name exists in a table then return value from another column or row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to find the corresponding header and position for each person in the attached table.  Basically I would like a formula in the green cells to pull the corresponding position number to the right of each name in column E and the bar name in row A.  What is the best way to do that?  For example, Gab would be Bar 2 and position 2, Nick would be Bar 4 position 3, etc.

Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXYXkN8ovwcJvVWN5-kHb0-N8sFIbVIP5qwesUPLCQw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

***Bar***

```
=tocol(index(if(A2:D7=A12,A1:D1,)),1)
```

***Position***

```
=tocol(index(if(A2:D7=A12,E2:E7,)),1)
```

[image]